# Schwinger metals?

Tags: electromagnetism, quantum-electrodynamics, plasma-physics

Consider an electromagnetic field that does reach values above the Schwinger limit inside a region of space $R$, on each oscillation.

Once the field exceeds the Schwinger intensity, the field causes a nonlinear response of vacuum charges that screens any excedent field. It would seem that any incoming electromagnetic radiation (within some spectrum) that hits the region boundary $R$, would experience a counter-field caused by the vacuum screened charges, that would induce a reflection of the radiation, just like in a metal mirror.

Can one understand this nonlinear phase of the electromagnetic field as a metal?

In particular, the region $R$ might exists for a brief period of time on each oscillation. If one were to beam electromagnetic waves toward the region $R$, would the beam become reflected?

Is there any wavelength one can consider the vacuum screening field to interact with external photons as a mirror?